# ros2 docker multiple hosts

Tags: ros, ros2, docker, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I get ROS2 to run in docker across multiple hosts reliably?  I have two hosts, on an ethernet network:

- Bridge networks do not support multicast
- Overlay networks do not support multicast
- macvlan networks cannot be accessed from the host machine (Workaround below)
- Host networks partially work, but I only see a random subset of the nodes on the network. (Workaround below)
- Weave network performance is very poor. (A simple topic that typically runs natively at 270Hz only manages to get up to 20Hz)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358453/ros2-docker-multiple-hosts/) by [dawonn_haval](https://answers.ros.org/users/52574/dawonn_haval/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2020-07-31

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There appear to be two potential workarounds:

**HOST:**

If you want to use host networking, you also much share the pid space so that each DDS node can generate a unique GUID. ( All thanks go to @ruffsl, more detail [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/296828/ros2-connectivity-across-docker-containers-via-host-driver/) )

```
docker run --rm -d --net=host --pid=host <IMAGE>
```

**MACVLAN:**

This workaround seems to work more often than not but sometimes the container needs to be restarted before it will see all nodes on the network.

```
docker network create -d macvlan \
    --subnet=192.168.1.0/24 \
    --gateway=192.168.1.1 \
    --ip-range=192.168.1.64/27 \
    --attachable \
    -o parent=enp8s0 \
    macnet

sudo ip link add macnet-shim link eth0 type macvlan  mode bridge
sudo ip addr add 192.168.1.64/27 dev macnet-shim
sudo ip link set macnet-shim up

docker run --rm -d --net=macnet <IMAGE>
```

---

Originally posted by [dawonn_haval](https://answers.ros.org/users/52574/dawonn_haval/) with karma: 103 on 2020-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3